# Finding a max number in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a simple way to find a max number in a array given below in JavaScript?

```
[3,4,[22,21],5,9,5]
```

`Math.max.apply(null,numbers)` gives `NaN`.

Comment: `[22,21]` is not a number. How should you count that when determining the max?

Comment: @ KT B: The lesson here is: 1. Be precise when asking your question. 2. Include expected results. 3. *Stick around* after asking it to clarify if needed.

Comment: should've just closed it as unclear what you're asking 53 minutes ago and walked away

Comment: To the poster, are you alive?

Answer (score 4):

Your example is an array with another array nested one level deep. Assuming only one level of nesting, first you [flatten the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript), then you apply the `Math.max` trick to it:

```js
var a = [3,4,[22,21],5,9,5];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, [].concat.apply([], a));
console.log(max);
```

Comment: @torazaburo: Indeed so. I've added that caveat.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a version of `reduce` which handles nested arrays.

```js
function nestedReduce(array, fn, initial) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, elt) {
    return fn(result, Array.isArray(elt) ? nestedReduce(elt, fn, initial) : elt);
  }, initial);
}

console.log(nestedReduce([3,4,[22,21],5,9,5], Math.max, -Infinity));
```

This will handle any level of nesting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursion with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

This works for multiple nested arrays.

```js
var array = [3, 4, [22, 21], 5, 9, 5, [[[42]]]],
    maxValue = array.reduce(function max(r, a, i) {
        var v = Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(max, undefined) : a;
        return !i || r < v ? v : r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(maxValue);
```

Edit suggested by [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo) with `-Infinity` and `Math.max`.

```js
var array = [3, 4, [22, 21], 5, 9, 5, [[[42]]]],
    maxValue = array.reduce(function max(r, a, i) {
        return Math.max(r, Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(max, -Infinity) : a);
    }, -Infinity);

console.log(maxValue);
```

Comment: To maintain the semantics of `Math.max`, the maximum of an empty array should be `-Infinity`, not `undefined`. That would also allow you to skip the `!i` check.

Comment: Even i haven't used reduce -:)

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follows;

```js
function getMax(a){
  return Math.max(...a.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? getMax(e) : e));
}
var arr = [3, 4, [22, 21], 5, 9, 5, [[[42]]], 41];
console.log(getMax(arr));
```